# quick sort and merge sort

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hey can someone tell me the basic algorithm for each and the tracing sequence for each. i'm confused there are many ways to it online and i don't really know which is the easiest/smartest. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "tracing sequence"? And what do you mean "many ways"? There is fundamentally only one algorithm called "quick sort" and one algorithm called "merge sort"; you may find different explanations of the algorithm, but it's still the same algorithm. There are only minor variations in the details; we can get around this by just being more general/vague in the description.

Comment: like the way the elements are divided and sorted after each step. or simply the array after each step of execution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244252/a-good-reference-card-cheat-sheet-with-the-basic-sort-algorithms-in-c/244632#244632

Comment: Wikipedia is a good place to start: [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) [Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, quicksort is a top-down approach while mergesort is a bottom-up approach. In quicksort, we select a "pivot" or "partition" value, and partition the list into two "halves" (not always exactly half, but the closer to half the better) - those less-than the pivot and those greater. We then recurse on those two halves and the result is that they are sorted.

A trace:

```
2, 3, 4, 1  (select pivot 3)
2, 1 | 3, 4 (partition < and >= partition)
1, 2 | 3, 4 (recursively sort halves)
1, 2, 3, 4  (done)
```

In merge sort, we divide the list into two halves (without sorting -- so it can be exactly half) then recursively sort the two halves. Then on the way up, we "merge" the two lists (themselves sorted but not partitioned). A trace:

```
2, 3, 4, 1
2, 3 | 4, 1 (cut in half)
2, 3 | 1, 4 (recursively sort halves)
1, 2, 3, 4  (merge; done)
```

Note the difference between the traces: in QS, we first get the lists partitioned so no item in the left list is greater than any in the right, but the lists themselves are unsorted. In MS, we first get the lists sorted, but they have no relationship across lists until the merge.

Both are N log N on average, but the performance details vary. Notably, quicksort can be done in-place, but its biggest flaw it having to choose a pivot. Choosing a bad pivot can result in not splitting in half, which can make for at worst O(N^2) performance. Merge sort always partitions exactly in half.

Comment: +1 It should be noted that not all quicksorts split in two - a common variant splits into `<`, `=`, and `>` segments which can mitigate the chances of N^2 performance (e.g. in common cases of pre-sorted and identical input elements)

Comment: what i don't get about merge sort is when you get down to `2,3|1,4`, both halves are sorted, but to "merge" them the lists still need to be interlaced...you can't just tack one onto the other. how's that part done?

Comment: @Ralph, merge sort can't be done in-place for precisely this reason - you need to allocate at least half as much as the full array (either manually or in stack space) to have some 'scratch space' to put the intermediate result in - i.e. what happens is you have 3 arrays `a=[2,3];b=[1,4];c=[];` then you loop and do something to the effect of `if (a[i]<b[j]) then c[k++]=a[i++]; else c[k++]=b[j++];` until one of the halves runs out...

Comment: @Ralph Sorry I didn't explain that in detail. The "merge" is a O(n) algorithm which takes two sorted lists (which aren't necessarily ordered with respect to each other) and forms a complete sorted list. To do this, look at the first element of the two lists, and decide which is smaller, and move it to the output list (`2, 3` vs `1, 4` -- pick 1), deleting it (or advancing a pointer) from the input list. Now you have `2, 3 | 4`. Now repeat (`2, 3` vs `4` -- pick 2). Repeat (`3` vs `4` -- pick 3). Until one of the lists is empty; then place the remaining list on the end: `1, 2, 3, 4`.

Comment: ohh...right! that makes sense. i learnt this before, but then i forgot :) rarely need to write your own sorting algorithm in practice.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this website might help you](http://math.hws.edu/TMCM/java/xSortLab/)

There is a java applet which renders a visualisation of the algorithms

Comment: Are there any applets that also trace the execution of the code? Rather than just a picture of what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

Also, a good randomized partition will pretty much eliminate the worst case for quicksort, so it'll be O(nlgn).

Comment: True. Choosing the partition is a tricky subject. What's interesting about it is that the *ideal* partition is the median value (exactly half-way), but finding the median value takes, I believe, O(n). So if you were to do that, you could get O(n log n) but it would be so costly it wouldn't be worth it. In practice, choosing a random pivot, as @Herberto suggests, is the best approach as you will get amortised O(n log n) even if in practice the pivot is a bit off.

Answer (score 1):

Invariant of quicksort is that each recursion downwards, the right side is always greater than or equal to the pivot and at least equal to the left side.

Whereas, mergesort that is not the case.  However, on the tail recursion, when the merging is performed, it is guaranteed that the sub-list of items at that recurision is ordered.

Answer (score 0):

quicksort picks a "pivot" point somewhere around the center of the array. It will then move all elements smaller than the pivot to the low part of the array, and all the elements equal to or above the pivot to the high part of the array. The pivot will go in the middle and be in it's correct location. Quicksort will then be called on the low portion of the array and the high part, but neither will include the pivot. When it gets down to two values, it will flip them if necessary and return.

Merge sort needs an extra array to put it's new values in, thus consuming more memory. The algorithm will call itself on the top and bottom parts of the array. When this eventually gets down to two or one element it will flip them if necessary and return. Once the two halfs are individually sorted, merge sort will then pick the smaller first value of the two arrays and place it in another array, continuing until both arrays have no values left. Merge sort will always be as fast as Quicksort, but it consumes more memory.